# MySQL error happens: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I'm currently self-studying to become a programmer and I've run into a little snag and can't seem to figure out why this particular code doesn't work...

I'm trying to create a list of movie titles that do no contain the word 'kill' or 'blood' in the title name and are of the genre thriller or horror (griezel in dutch :p).

For this I'm using the code below

```
SELECT filmId, titel, genre
FROM films
INNER JOIN genres ON films.genreId = genres.genreId
WHERE titel NOT LIKE ('%blood%', '%kill%')
  AND genre IN ('thriller', 'griezel')
```

When I try to execute this code is get an error message saying the following

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify multiple patterns like that.

You'll need to use separate `not like` predicates and `OR` them:

```
select filmId,
    titel,
    genre
from films
inner join genres on films.genreId = genres.genreId
where (
        titel not like '%blood%'
        or titel not like '%kill%'
        )
    and genre in ('thriller', 'griezel')
```

Or perhaps you meant to use `AND` to check the title doesn't contain both blood and kill

```
select filmId,
    titel,
    genre
from films
inner join genres on films.genreId = genres.genreId
where (
        titel not like '%blood%'
        and titel not like '%kill%'
        )
    and genre in ('thriller', 'griezel')
```